# How to reuse a clang AST matcher?

Tags: c++, libclang, clang-ast-matchers

I'm using AST matchers from lib clang to ensures that some code is present in the body of a `foo` function.

So all my matchers starts like this:

```cpp
auto matcher1 = functiondecl(hasname("foo"),
                 hasdescendant(...))));


auto matcher2 = functiondecl(hasname("foo"),
                 hasdescendant(...))));
```

I would like to deduplicate the `functiondecl(hasname("foo"), hasdescendant(...)` part.
So for example if I want to find a constructor, I can write

```cpp
auto ctor = inFoo(cxxConstructorExpr());
```

It seems that I could write my own matcher using `AST_MATCHER_P`, but I can't figure out how.

Can you show me an example of custom matcher to deduplicate the beginning of my matchers?

Comment: Wouldn't `template <class T> auto inFoo(T && f) { return functiondecl(hasname("foo"), hasdescendant(std::forward<T>(f))); }` work?

Comment: It seems to do the trick. If you could post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
template <class T> 
auto inFoo(T && f) 
{ 
  return functiondecl(hasname("foo"), hasdescendant(std::forward<T>(f))); 
}
```